# How to find a user in Telegram by id?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to share my friend's telegram contact via bot. But my friend does not have a telegram username. I know his id number. How can I share it?

I use PyTelegramBotApi. And my code is as follows:

```py
from telebot import TeleBot, types


bot = TeleBot(token=TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_bot(message):
    text = "My friend contact"
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Contact', url="tg://user?id=<1427022865>"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=text, reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling()
```

I read on the internet how to use url. But I make mistakes. Because: `url="tg://user?id=<1427022865>"`

How to use it properly? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

A bot can only send a message to a profile that has already activated the bot.

So make your friend "start" the bot, than the code should work